# Program for calculating the time before the event starts in days

Tags: c#, datetime, events

I wrote a program that calculates the number of days before the event, there may be several events, I would like to know how to reduce or simplify this code.

```
   namespace Determining_the_time_before_the_event_starts
{
    class Program
    {
        struct Event
    {
        public string name;
        public DateTime time;
    }
    static Event[] InPutEvents()
    {
        Console.Write("Number of events: ");
        int n, year, month, day, hour, min;
        n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Event[] time = new Event[n];
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
                Console.Write("Event name: ");
                time[i].name = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Write("Event start year: ");
                year = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("Month of the beginning of the event: ");
                month = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("The first day of the event: ");
                day = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("Watch the beginning of the event: ");
                hour = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("Minutes before the event starts: ");
                min = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                time[i].time = new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, min, 0);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            return time;
    }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Event[] time = InPutEvents();
            Console.WriteLine();
            BeginEvent(time);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        static void BeginEvent (Event[] time)
        {
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            for(int i = 0; i < time.Length; i++)
            {
                SearchTime(time[i], now);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
        static void SearchTime(Event time, DateTime now)
        {
            int year, month, day, hour, min;
            year = time.time.Year - now.Year;
            month = time.time.Month - now.Month;
            day = time.time.Day - now.Day;
            hour = time.time.Hour - now.Hour;
            min = time.time.Minute - now.Minute;
            if (min < 0)
            {
                min += 60;
                hour--;
            }
            if (min > 60)
            {
                min -= 60;
                hour++;
            }
            if (hour < 0)
            {
                hour += 24;
                day--;
            }
            if (hour > 24)
            {
                 hour -= 24;
                day++;
            }
            if (day < 1)
            {
                day += 31;
                month--;
            }
            if (day > 31)
            {
                day -= 31;
                month++;
            }
            if (month < 1)
            {
                month += 12;
                year--;
            }
            if (month > 12)
            {
                month -= 12;
                year++;
            }
            day += (month * 31) + (year * 365);
            Console.WriteLine($"Event {time.name} starts in {day} days, {hour}hours, and {min}m. ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "I would like to know how to reduce or simplify this code" --> You have two DateTimes (one in your Event struct, and DateTime.Now), just [Subtract()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.subtract?view=netframework-4.8#System_DateTime_Subtract_System_DateTime_) them to get a [TimeSpan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: private static void PrintTimeDiff(DateTime time, DateTime now)
        {
            var eventName = "TestEvent";
            var diff = time - now;

            Console.WriteLine($"Event {eventName} starts in {diff.Days} days, {diff.Hours}hours, and {diff.Minutes}m. ");
        }

Answer (score 0):

Subtracting a `DateTime` object from another `DateTime` Object creates a `TimeSpan` object. The `TimeSpan` object has properties like `Days`, `Hours`, `Minutes` and so forth.

Simply use these properties to build the solution you need.

```
    private static void SearchTime(Event event, DateTime now)
    {
        var diff = event.time - now;

        Console.WriteLine($"Event {event.name} starts in {diff.Days} days, {diff.Hours}hours, and {diff.Minutes}m. ");
    }
```